# Beamer: reformat title text in definition block

Tags: beamer

I am using the Monterey theme in Beamer which displays definition block titles as

> Definition (My Definition)

I would like to change that to

> Definition: My Definition

```
\documentclass{beamer}  
\usetheme{Monterey}

\begin{document}
    
    
\begin{frame}
    \begin{definition}[My Definition]
        A definition
    \end{definition}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Here is my example]

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. This would be a better fit for [tex.se].

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to redefine the `theorem begin` template:

```
\documentclass{beamer}  
%\usetheme{Monterey}

\usecolortheme{orchid}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{theorem begin}
{%
  \begin{\inserttheoremblockenv}
  {%
    \inserttheoremname
    \ifx\inserttheoremaddition\@empty\else : \inserttheoremaddition\fi%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    
    
\begin{frame}
    \begin{definition}[My Definition]
        A definition
    \end{definition}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]